# `dplyr::select(num_range())` when the number is in middle of column name

Tags: r, dplyr

In the data below, there are column names for units (1 - 8). Each unit has a column for the score and for the percent. Is there a way to use `dplyr::select()` with the `num_range()` helper to select, say, only units 1-3 for the scores? I can get it if I drop the suffix (so it's just unit_1 instead of unit_1_score), but otherwise my attempts have been unsuccessful. I've tried `dplyr::select(d, num_range("unit_", 1:3, "_score"))` but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
d <- readr::read_csv("https://data.jacksonms.gov/api/views/97iy-g8hk/rows.csv")
d <- janitor::clean_names(d)
names(d)

 [1] "test_year"             "test_type"             "test_site"             "student_id"           
 [5] "pre_test_score"        "pre_test_percent"      "post_test_score"       "post_test_percent"    
 [9] "percentage_change"     "unit_1_score"          "unit_1_percent"        "unit_2_score"         
 [13] "unit_2_percent"        "unit_3_score"          "unit_3_percent"        "unit_4_score"         
 [17] "unit_4_percent"        "unit_5_6_score"        "unit_5_6_percent"      "unit_7_score"         
 [21] "unit_7_percent"        "unit_8_score"          "unit_8_percent"        "total_score"          
 [25] "total_percent_correct"
```

Comment: You have a `unit_5_6_score` column? Would you expect that to work with both `3:5` and `6:8`?

Comment: How about `dplyr::select(d, paste0("unit_", 1:3, "_score"))`?

Comment: Yeah I realize that (not my data), but that was part of why I asked about 1-3. Trying to understand the more general case.

Comment: @ycw that's nice, and probably preferable. I was mostly trying to understand how num_range works. I guess the number just has to be at the end?

Comment: @DanielAnderson I am not familiar with `num_range` but you could be right. The numbers may need to be at the end.

Comment: num_range only takes a prefix and a number. The number has to be the last thing, yes. It's kinda weird.

Comment: Thanks. That's really the answer I was looking for. Thanks for your help, everybody.

Answer (score 4):

We could select columns with a regex range using `dplyr::matches()`:

```
select(d, matches("unit_[1-3]_score"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this answer is not perceived as off-topic; I am assuming you would be happy with a valid response even if it does not use `dplyr`.

You can easily select certain columns in a `data.frame` using regular expressions. To select only units 1-3, for example, try: `d[, grep(x = colnames(d), pattern = "^unit_[1-3]{1}_.*$)"]` This will select the columns in `d` that have column names starting with "unit_" followed by 1, 2, or 3 (only one time), and then zero or more of anything afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that and use it regularly, but I was really just trying to understand the behavior of num_range.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding that the `5_6` column is going to be tricky (who thought that was a good idea!?), you might find the new tidyeval concepts useful for this.
The `syms` function in the `rlang` package and the new `!!!` expansion method work together to solve this kind of problem:

```r
dplyr::select(d, !!!rlang::syms(paste0("unit_", 1:3, "_score")))
#> # A tibble: 48 x 3
#>    unit_1_score unit_2_score unit_3_score
#>           <int>        <int>        <int>
#>  1            3            4            6
#>  2            5            5            6
#>  3            4            4            6
#>  4            4            4            6
#>  5            2            5            6
#>  6            5            5            7
#>  7            5            5            6
#>  8            4            5            5
#>  9            6            4            5
#> 10            4            5            5
#> # ... with 38 more rows
```

Explaining exactly what this does is somewhat tricky (try reading `vignette("tidy-evaluation")`) but it works, so there's that :)

Though actually, just using strings works now so maybe you don't need to bother?

```r
dplyr::select(d, paste0("unit_", 1:3, "_score"))
#> # A tibble: 48 x 3
#>    unit_1_score unit_2_score unit_3_score
#>           <int>        <int>        <int>
#>  1            3            4            6
#>  2            5            5            6
#>  3            4            4            6
#>  4            4            4            6
#>  5            2            5            6
#>  6            5            5            7
#>  7            5            5            6
#>  8            4            5            5
#>  9            6            4            5
#> 10            4            5            5
#> # ... with 38 more rows
```